# Video Onclick function for playing a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have designed a video question using Html and i have removed controls for video using Jquery, so i need to have onclick functionality like when we click on the video it should be played and if am clicking again it should be paused .

Comment: Where do you `click`? can you post some code?

Comment: Something like this `$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('YOUR_VIDEO_ID').click(function() {
        $(this).get(0).paused ? $(this).get(0).play() : $(this).get(0).pause();
    });
});`

Comment: Thank you  @SandeepNayak

Comment: I ll post that as an answer then!

Answer (score 2):

> Below your html code

```
  <video id="video" width="1180" height="664" poster="put here your poster url" preload="auto">
        <source src="put here your video url" type="video/mp4">      
   </video>
```

> Below jquery code

```
  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  video.addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
        if (video.paused == true) {
             video.play();
        }
        else{
             video.pause();
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `play` or `pause` a vide like this. This should be able to toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('YOUR_VIDEO_ID_OR_CLASS').click(function(){ 
       $(this).get(0).paused ? $(this).get(0).play() : $(this).get(0).pause(); 
    }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way could be like this:

```
$(function() {
    var video = $('video')[0];
    $('button').click(function() {
        if( video.paused ) {
            video.play();
        }
        else {
            video.pause();
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/28gjspch/)

You can change `'button'` to another element as trigger for the play/pause.
You can also change it to the video it self, if you want just to click on the video to play and pause it.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function vidplay() { 
var video = document.getElementById("Video1"); 
var button = document.getElementById("play"); 
if (video.paused) { 
video.play(); 
button.textContent = "||";
 } 
else 
{ 
video.pause(); 
button.textContent = ">"; 
} 
} 
</script>
```